# Asking about final letters

Tags: hebrew, aleph-bet-letters

Is there a specific reason that when letters such as mem & nun are written at the end of a sentence they are written differently?

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75586/midrash-genesis-rabbah-1-11-clarification-to-the-answer-the-children-recieved?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Midrash Genesis Rabbah 1.11 -- clarification to the answer the children recieved about the two forms for mem, nun, zade, peh, & kaf?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75586/midrash-genesis-rabbah-1-11-clarification-to-the-answer-the-children-recieved)

Comment: Chris, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887)! Are you asking whether Judaism the religion provides an explanation about these differences? If so, please [edit] to make that clear and preferably to also explain why you suspect that Judaism may have something to say about this.

Comment: In general, it can be assumed that whatever is in your title is what you are asking about. No need to explicitly label it as such.

Comment: The answer is that Aramaic and other ancient languages were often carved on stone and therefore people would not use spaces between words, so all the letters would run on and on. Final letters were invented so that way one could distinguish the end of words without needing spaces. Mems were chosen for Jewish Aramaic because a lot of Hebrew words end in mem. The final nun was invented by the Aramaic speakers since Aramaic has a lot of words that end in nun.